# how to call a method when change in field using angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I am entering numbers in two fields and showing another field using arithmetic calculation.In that I wanna one call and that calculation and want to calculate using input type=" text" only not a number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        First Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstvalue">
        <br> Last Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="lastvalue">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br> Total:
        <input type="text" ng-model="total=firstvalue + lastvalue" ng-change="changed()" disabled="disabled">
        <br>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.changed = function() {
                alert("Total" + $scope.total);
            };
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

i want to sum those two value.want show the sum in third field and also when change the third field need to call one function like ng-change that field need to disable.

Comment: how can you add two string variables? :O

Comment: Try this `<input type="text" ng-value="total=firstName + lastName" ng-model="total"`

Comment: Maybe you would like to change the text field names ? I don't think you want to arithmetically add first and last names , right....

Comment: Maybe he wants something like 'one' in first input , 'two' in second input and total should be 'three'

Comment: i want to sum those two value.want show the sum in third field and also when change the third field need to call one function like ng-change that field need to disable.

Answer (score 1):

You have very weird and unclear requirement. But this should help - https://jsfiddle.net/4qohy46L/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        First Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-change="recalculate()">
        <br> Last Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"  ng-change="recalculate()">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br> Total:
        <input type="text" ng-model="total">
        <br>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.recalculate = function() {
                    var tempFirst = 0, tempSecond = 0
                    if($scope.firstName)
                    tempFirst = $scope.firstName;
              if($scope.lastName)
                    tempSecond = $scope.lastName;
                $scope.total = parseInt(tempFirst)  + parseInt(tempSecond);
            };
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Please feel free to tell me if I have not correctly understood your question. And always prepare a fiddle or a plunker when you post a question on SO it makes it easier for people who want to help you :)

Comment: Thanks quick reply,but i don't want those calculation controller.need to have function call is when third field changes.

Comment: @Maxi doesnt change a lot of things, the idea stays the same. You can parse and add it.